# Word formatting to equivalent HTML

Tags: html, vba, ms-word

Sorry for not being clear at the first time. Here is my need.

I am trying to write a VBA script to convert simple word text formatting to HTML.
Now I know that Word already can convert documents to HTML but it add's far to much junk code for the end result to be of use to me.

Basically all I need is very very simple text formatting conversion. I have several word documents I need to upload to my website the only text formatting that is in my documents are "Bold" "Underline" and "Italics".

I simply want a VBA script that will run through the document and convert all text  (words or sentances) that have this formatting to HTML.

for example

**The cat was sleepy** .... changed to .... The cat was sleepy

*The cat was sleepy* .... changed to .... The cat was sleepy

I wish to save the end result as plain text file.

P.S I am a novoice to VBA programming .

I would want to do this in MS word 2007.

Comment: To make it answerable you need to explain how built in functionality does not work for you. Also answers may depend on where do you want to perform conversion and what versions of Office you need to support OR if you need standalone tool.

Answer (score -1):

The topic starter apparently frowns on the amount of extra needless tags which are always inserted by own Microsoft's converter. To write a macro, you just need to learn appropriate features of the Document Object Model (DOM). DOM is described in the built-in help system, which can invoked from within VBA editor which comes with MS Office. But this task is more difficult than it can be viewed at the first glance, because you'll inevitably face with some strangeness of MS Word when processing some documents. So a better solution would be to use third-party tool for this task.